# can use limit in subquery?

Tags: php, mysql

I want show comment in admin, and in each page i show 20 commnets. I wants to set seen field of this 20 commnets to 1. I use this query which is give me error

```
public static function seen_comment($per_page,$offset){
        global $db;
        $sql =" UPDATE ".self::$table_name; 
        $sql.=" SET seen=1";
        $sql.=" WHERE id IN  ";
        $sql.=" ( SELECT id FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC )";
        $sql.=" LIMIT $per_page OFFSET $offset ";

        $db->query($sql);
}
```

**whats the problem? whats the best approach for this condition?**

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OFFSET 0' at line 1' in C:\wamp\www\1hezar\inc\class\comment.php on line 89

Comment: Can you echo the query? Presumably there's no value for $per_page

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out

```
<?php 
 public static  function seen_comment($per_page,$offset){
    global $db;
    $sql =" UPDATE ".self::$table_name ." 
            SET `seen`=1  
            WHERE `id` 
            IN  ( SELECT id FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $per_page OFFSET $offset ) ";
    $db->query($sql);
 }
?>
```

Hope it works

Comment: can you post the query what you get after calling the function